# The following StackOverflowError was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty, state: _ObxState#896e1): Stack Overflow

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

I'm using Getx package in my Flutter project, but some thing went wrong!!!

In class controller I made a stream connection with firestore to fetch data and put them in a List..

In the ui class That I want to show data in, I can call the data in ListView.builder or any thing else by using `Obx`, but when I try to call data in DropdownButtonFormField, using `Obx` or `Getx` widgets.. The error occurred suddenly.

When I use a none stream widget like `Getbuilder` the error never appers, but no data will be loaded!!

Error message:

`======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= The following StackOverflowError was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty, state: _ObxState#896e1): Stack Overflow`

Here is the controller class:

```
class AddEmployeeController extends GetxController {

final CollectionReference _villagesCollectionRef =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Categories');

  RxList<String> villageNames = RxList([]);

@override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    villageNames.bindStream(villagesNamesList());
  }

Stream<List<String>> villagesNamesList() {
    return _villagesCollectionRef.snapshots().map((QuerySnapshot query) {
      for (var element in query.docs) {
        villageNames.add(element['name']);
      }
      return villageNames;
    });
  }

}
```

And Here is The class where I want to show data:

```
class CreateAccount extends StatelessWidget {
  CreateAccount({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final AddEmployeeController addEmployeeController =
      Get.put(AddEmployeeController());

  final String value = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
        title: titleText(
          text: 'Create Account',
          size: Dimensions.font20,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: addEmployeeController.formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height40),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Obx(
                  () => SizedBox(
                    width: Dimensions.width200,
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                      focusColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_down_rounded),
                      decoration: inputDecoration(),
                      value: addEmployeeController.startingVillageName,
                      items: addEmployeeController.villageNames
                          .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: item,
                                child: Text(item),
                              ))
                          .toList(),
                      onChanged: addEmployeeController.changeDropdownValue(value),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does any body have a solution !!!

Comment: Did you assign a default value as an initial value for the dropdown?, what is the initial value of addEmployeeController.startingVillageName ?

Comment: @WilliamsBobadilla ofcourse I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had reached to the solution, I change the stream properties in the controller class..

I change it from List to List as the attached:

```
Stream<List<VillageModel>> villagesNamesList() {
    return _villagesCollectionRef
        .orderBy('name', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .map((QuerySnapshot query) {
      vilNames.add('choose village');
      vilValue = vilNames.first;
      for (var element in query.docs) {
        vilNames.add(element['name']);
      }
      update();
      return villageModel;
    });
  }
```

And in the ui class this is changes:

```
GetBuilder<AddSubscriberController>(
                        builder: (controller) => SizedBox(
                          width: Dimensions.width300,
                          child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                            focusColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_down_rounded),
                            decoration: inputDecoration(),
                            value: controller.vilValue,
                            items: controller.vilNames
                                .map(
                                  (item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: item,
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: titleText(
                                        text: item,
                                        size: Dimensions.font16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                                .toList(),
                            onChanged: controller.changeVillageValue,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```